# MFCのCArrayで独自クラスを利用する際の書き方

Tags: c++, mfc

MFCタグが作れなかったのでC++タグで失礼いたします。(2014/12/17 16時27分提案→MFCタグ追加済)

今MFCを学んでおります。

現在MFCのSDIで図形作成プログラムを作っていて、Viewにすべてのデータを持たせてDocに保存していましたが、データが増えてきたので別クラスにてデータを管理しようとしています。

保存するデータとして
・図形が何個あるのか
・図形の座標
を考えており、数を制限したくないので可変にするためにCArrayで管理しようとしています。
CArrayを独自クラスで利用する際の書き方がよくわかりませんので下記コードだとどうなるか具体的に教えていただければ幸いです。

CPaintData.h

```
class CPaintData : public CObject
{
public:
    CPaintData();
    virtual ~CPaintData();

private:
    int m_nFigureNumber;        // 図形の数
    double m_dCoodinateX;       // 各種X座標
    double m_dCoodinateY;       // 各種Y座標

public:
    void setFigureNumber(int Number);       //現在の図形の数
    double getFigureNumber(void);
    void setCoodinateX(CPoint point);       //現在のX座標の取得
    double getCoodinateX(void);
    void setCoodinateY(CPoint point);       //現在のY座標の取得
    double getCoodinateY(void);
};
```

CPaintData.cpp

```
CPaintData::CPaintData()
: m_dCoodinateX(0)
{
}

CPaintData::~CPaintData()
{
}

void CPaintData::setCoodinateX(CPoint point)        // 現在のX座標の取得
{
    m_dCoodinateX = point.x;
}

double CPaintData::getCoodinateX(void)
{
    return m_dCoodinateX;
}
```

(↑同じような形なので図形の数とY座標は省略)

CPaintView.h

```
#include "atltypes.h"
#include "PaintData.h"

enum{   
        DRAW_LINE = 1,
        DRAW_TRIANGLE,
        DRAW_SQUARE,
        DRAW_CIRCLE_CONTINUE,
        DRAW_POLYLINE_CONTINUE
};

class CScrollViewPaintView : public CView
{
public:
    afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
    CArray<CPaintData, CPaintData&> m_arDataArray;

};
```

(↑必要そうなところだけ抜粋)

CPaintView.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Paint.h"

#include "PaintDoc.h"
#include "PaintView.h"

(省略)

void CScrollViewPaintView::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) //左クリック時の処理
{
    if(m_nType == DRAW_CIRCLE){     //メニューで円を選んだとき
        CPaintDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();    //Docを使うために必要
        ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);

        CPaintData PaintData;           //このあたりからよくわからない

        PaintData.setCoodinateX(point.x);   //setできてる模様？
        PaintData.setCoodinateY(point.y);   //setできてる模様？
        PaintData.getCoodinateX();      //getできるけどVSで見るとm_arDataArrayに入っていない模様でどこからとってるのか謎
        PaintData.getCoodinateY();      //getできてない？

        //ここでクリックが2回目なら、1回目を中心、2回目を外周のどこかとする円を書く処理にとばす

        //図形の個数をプラス1する

        pDoc->SetModifiedFlag();        //Docに保存
    }

}
```

CPaintDoc(今回は関係ないはずなので省略)

開発環境はwin7 64bit VS2010です。
よろしくおねがいいたします。

Comment: 知りたいのは、独自クラス(`CPaintData`)の可変長配列(`CArray`)を作り、そこに新要素を追加／要素を参照する方法ですか？ offtopicですが @NobuhideTsuda さんも指摘されている通り、MFC `CArray`よりもC++標準ライブラリの`std::vector`を使った方が良いかと思います

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentのメンバーに以下を登録。

```
　CArray <CPaintData *, CPaintData *> m_aryPaint;
```

追加時のコードは以下。

```
  CPaintData *pPaint = new CPaintData();
  pPaint->データ設定
　GetDocument()->m_aryPaint.Add(pPaint);
```

読み出しと描画は以下。

```
  for (int i = 0; i < GetDocument()->m_aryPaint.GetCount(); i++)
  {
     CPaintData *pPaint = GetDocument()->m_aryPaint.GetAt(i);
     描画処理
  }
```

こんな感じでしょうか。
削除は以下。

```
  for (int i = 0; i < GetDocument()->m_aryPaint.GetCount(); i++)
  {
     delete GetDocument()->m_aryPaint.GetAt(i);
  }
　 GetDocument()->m_aryPaint.RemoveAll();
```

Comment: コードと説明が分割されていなかったので、体裁を修正しました。

Answer (score 4):

期待される解答とはちょっと違うかもしれませんが、現状であれば、MFC独自の CArray を使うよりは、標準ライブラリの std::vector を使うことを強くお薦めします。
その方が、情報も多いですし、普遍性が高いです。

具体的な使い方ですが、複数の座標値を管理したいのであれば、

```
struct Pos {
   double m_x;
   double m_y;
};
```

のような構造体を作り、CPaintData のメンバ変数として、その動的配列を保持すればいいと思います。

```
class CPaintData {
private:
  std::vector<Pos> m_posList;  //  座標データたち
};
```

std::vector の使い方そのものは、手前味噌ですが
[C++ 動的配列クラス std::vector 入門](http://vivi.dyndns.org/tech/cpp/vector.html) 等を参照してください。

Answer (score 3):

こんな感じですかね？

```
Carray <CPaintData , CPaintData &> arPaintData;
CPaintData PaintData;
Cpoint cpWk;
cpWk.x = 123;
cpWk.y = 456;
PaintData.setCoodinateX(cpWk);
PaintData.setCoodinateY(cpWk);
arPaintData.Add(PaintData);
```

Answer (score 2):

もとのソースと関係なく、概念だけ書くと、こんな感じでしょうか。

その方がいろいろと都合が良いので、CArrayは図形のポインタを保持するものとします。

```
// CArrayでクラスのポインタを保持するテンプレート

template< typename T >

class T_PTR_ARY : public CArray< T*>{

public:

    T_PTR_ARY(){}

    virtual ~T_PTR_ARY(){ Destroy();}

    void Destroy(){

    ・・・・// 全てのT*をdelete してから

        RemoveAll(); // 全て廃棄

    }

};


class FIG {・・・・};// 図形の基本クラス

typedef T_PTR_ARY< FIG>  FIG_ARY;// 図形のポインタの配列クラス

class FIG_RECT:public FIG{}; // 図形の派生クラス　矩形

// 実際に使うときは

FIG_ARY fig_ary;

fig_ary.Add( new FIG_RECT); // 矩形を追加
```

Comment: コードの体裁を修正しました。スペース4個で字下げするとコードブロックになります。

Answer (score 1):

CObjectから派生させてる事から察しますが…
MFCのシリアライズ機能を使う予定であればCArrayを使う方が良い(必須ではない)ですよ。